# Docker compose working fine unless deployed with simple Ansible playbook

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, ansible, ftp

I have a simple docker-compose file containing an FTP server and Monitoring tool.

Using **docker compose up** the FTP is working fine and is accessible from the internet but when I deploy the docker compose using Ansible docker compose module the FTP server isn't accessible. Strange is that the monitoring tool is still accessible even when deployed through ansible.

Docker compose file (only FTP part):

```
services:
  ftp:
    container_name: test_ftp
    image: stilliard/pure-ftpd
    ports:
      - 21:21
      - 30000-30009:30000-30009
    volumes:
      - './ftp/data:/home/username/'
      - './ftp/pass:/etc/pure-ftpd/passwd'
    environment:
      PUBLICHOST: "my.public.ip.address"
      FTP_USER_NAME: "username"
      FTP_USER_PASS: "password"
      FTP_USER_HOME: "/home/username"
    restart: always
```

Ansible playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Deploy docker compose
    community.docker.docker_compose:
      project_src: /home/myusername/test_project
      files:
      - docker-compose.yml
```

docker ps command after running Ansible playbook:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                            PORTS                                                                                                                        NAMES
ddcbde7178d3   stilliard/pure-ftpd   "/bin/sh -c '/run.sh…"   7 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds                      21/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30000-30009->30000-30009/tcp, :::30000-30009->30000-30009/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49155->1281/tcp, :::49155->1281/tcp   test_ftp
```

How can I make the FTP server accessible when deploying through Ansible?

Ubuntu 22.04 server in Azure

Comment: I would check volume mounts, there are relative paths. Maybe ansible launches docker-compose in a different way. Check actual mounts with `docker inspect`

Comment: The actual mounts are the same when deployed using ansible and docker compose up

Comment: What about ports? Are the same ports exposed?

Comment: Yes, the ports were the issue! Changed 21:21 to 0.0.0.0:21:21 in the docker compose file and now I can access the FTP even when deployed with Ansible. Thank you